# Function returns named vector without names

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that makes a named vector such as:

```
> x
  a   b   c 
"i" "j" "k"
```

But following function:

```
getNamedCharacter <- function() {
  x[c("a", "b", "c")] <- c("i", "j", "k")
}
```

...returns vector without names:

```
> x <- getNamedCharacter()
> x
[1] 1 2 3
```

...while the line of code itself works as expected:

```
> x <- NULL
> x[c("a", "b", "c")] <- c("i", "j", "k")
> x
  a   b   c 
"i" "j" "k"
```

How can I get named vector with names using a function?
Thanks!

Comment: add `return(x)` in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `structure`. Possibly also adding attributes:

```
make_named_vec <- function(vec, vec_names){
  structure(vec, names = vec_names)
 }
 make_named_vec(c("i","j","k"), c("a","b","c"))
  a   b   c 
"i" "j" "k"

res <-make_named_vec(c("i","j","k"), c("a","b","c"))
 str(res)
 Named chr [1:3] "i" "j" "k"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check the structure(). But I don't provide names and strings as a function parameters, it's all inside the function.

Comment: Sorry I'm away from my computer. This is just an alternative implementation. If you just want to add attributes to a vector, try `attr`. Otherwise I guess just using return is sufficient. I however find the syntax a bit confusing and think explicitly stating that you're naming might be better. Opinionated.

Comment: Looks like just adding 'return(x)' to my function solves the problem. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign names to a vector by using `names(vector) <- namesvector`:

**The Function**

```
getnamedCharacter <- function(vector, names){
  names(vector) <- names
  return(vector)
}
```

**Result**

```
getnamedCharacter(c("i", "j", "k"), c("a", "b", "c"))

 a   b   c 
"i" "j" "k"
```

Comment: Thanks. It does not work by the way as I use my function without parameters. With little change it works: 
**The Function**
`getNamedCharacter <- function() {
  x <- c("i", "j", "k")
  names(x) <- c("a", "b", "c")
  return(x)
}`
**Result**
`> x <- getNamedCharacter()
> x
  a   b   c 
"i" "j" "k"`
I am mostly interested why the function acting like that.